# Moving Joomla SEF rules from .htaccess to vhosts.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, virtualhost, vhosts

I have a joomla install which uses the built in SEF urls, and the stock .htaccess file to rewrite them.

I presume that it would be much more efficient to set the rules in the apache config rather than .htaccess, [to avoid having this file requested and parsed for every file load]  but am having trouble finding a reference for it,

So I moved the rules from .htaccess to the vhosts.conf file.

I am now getting 400 bad requests for the pages with the SEF urls.

Can anyone suggest what the issue or offer any suggestions ?

**UPDATE**

It seem that the base was the issue, just need to change the rewrite rule from:

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
to
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L]
```

Comment: the .htaccess file is here, it's just the one that come with joomla https://gist.github.com/vool/4770127

Answer (score 0):

where in the vhosts.conf file have you placed these rules? they should be in the

```
<Directory /path/to/joomla> 
  #your rules here
</Directory>
```

inside the Vhost definition

Comment: Yes that's where I places them, I know the rules are being applied as I added one to to remove www. from the url and that is working fine.